# dynamic content on pages

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm trying to migrate all "content" pages on a website to DNN5 Pro.

So I just created all the pages in DNN, added HTML module to the ContentPane and copied and pasted the HTML content from old pages.

The problem is that most of the pages have bits of classic asp code which do some minor server-side tasks - for example, populate tables with prices fetched from DB, pre-select user's country based on his IP address, do some basic dates calculations, etc.

Obviously, this code won't work in DNN.

If I had to migrate to PHP, I'd just rewrite these bits of code from classic ASP to PHP, then assign values from PHP to smarty and then would use them in templates.

But as DNN has a completely different architecture, I can't see how similar approach can be used.

Token replacement feature in HTML module looks like what I need, but it allows to "map" only tokens provided by DNN.

So, maybe anyone had similar issue with DNN and/or knows how this should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write code directly in your skin file.  Do some logic like:

```
<%If PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID = 33 Then

//code here of what you want

End If%>
```

Where 33 is the page id for the page you want to run custom code on.  There are other ways to do this like creating skin objects, or creating custom modules, but this is probably the easiest thing to do. Just write code directly in you skin.  Or make a copy of your skin for each page you need to do custom code for... again, more elegant ways but this will get'er done.

Comment: sorry, but that sounds like a terrible idea. If you're just going to create a custom skin file for every DNN page, what's the point of using DNN. Functionality should be placed in modules (and occasionally skin objects) not directly in the skin.

Comment: It still depends.  I was posting the easiest solution for Vitaly.  Based on his comment above he said 'minor'.  He is new to the framework and I don't expect him to start cranking out a custom module for each page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are attempting to subvert the entire point of DotNetNuke. While certainly there are a variety of hacky ways you could try to make this work just like the php site, it's a terrible idea to do so.

Instead, you need to evaluate each of the dynamic sections of the php site and find or create a DotNetNuke module that will replicate that functionality.

To make the initial conversion quicker, you can build modules you create using simple ASP style inline scripting but you should definitely use existing modules for things like displaying data in a grid.

Comment: Could you post some resources for Vitaly to get started with module development using this technique?  Would probably help him get started on doing anything more complex.  Also referencing any modules by name would probably be of some use as well.  The core Reports module can show data in 'a grid' but I don't find it very useful for much. TressleWorks components on the other hand, excellent.

Comment: I know that I'm taking the wrong approach, but the goal is to migrate at least content pages as soon as possible - and THEN I can start moving the whole website to DNN modules. So I was just searching the quickest (and it turns out to be the dirtiest) way to do so.

Comment: I understand sometimes you need to use the fastest approach and go back later and do cleanup (though often this cleanup never occurs). I just don't think skins is the place to do it. The newest versions of DNN make simple custom module development really easy. It generates the files and definitions for you, you just add script to the ascx file it creates. Also, Shawn Walker posted a nice blog on quick inline scripting recently. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/2832/Inline-Script-Module-Development-in-DotNetNuke.aspx.

Comment: There are also some DNN modules out there that let you load any ascx file. We've got our own unreleased version but I know I've seen announcements for others. This could be a good temporary solution as well. You wouldn't have to create a module for everything and could just write all your code into the ascx file.